# How to rotate a photo that is picked from the photo library for editing

Tags: ios, camera, rotation, photo

In my app, I have a feature where you can share a photo to facebook. Before sharing, you can take a photo from the camera, or choose a photo from the photo library. Also, after you chose the photo, you can "edit" it (square crop <-- this is the basic feature that comes with the imagepicker).

Now, my question is, in my photo library, I have some photos that are in landscape, and I want to rotate them upwards before showing the "edit" screen. Is it possible?

I noticed that when you take a photo with the camera in landscape, the imagepicker auto rotates the photo upwards. But when I pick a photo that is in landscape in my library, it's not upwards.

Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only rotate the photo after the user has selected it from the image picker. Or the user must rotate it using the photos app beforehand.

Comment: "Or the user must rotate it using the photos app beforehand." That can be done only outside of my app right (that means from Apple's photo app only)? Is there a way to do the rotate image inside my app when the user is picking the photo from the library?

Comment: As I said only after image picking has finished including editing ( imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still running into this problem, but I figured I'd share some of my knowledge just in case you're still wondering...

I ran into this problem a while back with rotating images in iOS and ended up doing a lot of research into it.

Perhaps my SO question [iOS PNG Image rotated 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307521/ios-png-image-rotated-90-degrees/10369402#10369402) and the code I used to rotate the image will help?